# Добавление строки ИТОГО в DataGrid - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Имеется DataGrid с заведомо неизвестным числом столбцов и строк.
При запуске приложения считывается конфиг-файл и на его основе генерируется коллекция столбцов:

```
<DataGrid Name="lstInfo"
          Margin="5"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
```

---

```
    lstInfo.Columns.Add((DataGridColumn)Resources["colDistrict"]);
    for (int i = 0; i < Queries.Count; ++i)
        lstInfo.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = Queries[i].Name, Binding = new Binding($"Values[{i}]") { Mode = BindingMode.OneWay } });
    lstInfo.Columns.Add((DataGridColumn)Resources["colProgressBar"]);
```

Теперь есть задача вывести последней строкой грида (ну или скорее всего просто под гридом, не важно - как получится) строчку "ИТОГО". 
Как это сделать?

Пока как временное решение - добавил снизу еще один DataGrid без заголовков, такое решение в принципе устраивает, но теперь нужна привязка ширины столбцов к ширине столбцов верхнего DataGrid
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: В чем сложность? Значение "итого" сумма по одному какому то столбцу или же на каждый столбец свое "итого"?

Comment: Сложность в том, что к DataGrid.ItemsSource привязана коллекция и добавить "чужеродный" элемент (который бы подсчитывал сумму) плохое кривое решение. Должен добавляться элемент снизу, который бы имел такое же количество столбцов, что и в DataGrid, а также при изменении ширины столбцов DataGrid изменялась и ширина столбцов этого элемента. Где-то на enSO находил подобное решение для ListView/GridView с использованием GridViewRowPresenter, но здесь отличие в том, что заранее неизвестно количество столбцов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге реализовал все-таки в виде дополнительной строки в том же DataGrid - написал базовый абстрактный класс и строки-данные, строку-итого наследовал от этого класса. Пришлось использовать 2 коллекции - первая только для строк-данных, вторая - для всех строк, которые выводятся в DataGrid.

Решение с двумя DataGrid отверг из-за того, что не понял как привязать ширину столбцов второго грида к первому, ну и необходимо было что-то делать со скроллингом по горизонтали.